# React native expo not running in Simulator

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am getting below error while running application in simulator.
I tried to restart server but not work for me

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same issue, solved by below steps

- Update expo version by `npm install -g expo-cli`
- Restart server
- Run application

For me,

1. Previous Expo version : `3.11.7`
2. Updated Expo version :  `3.18.0`

Hope it helps